# Swift: segue to another ViewController from a custom dialog

Tags: swift, segue

I have a Custom Dialog which returns to its caller when I use Dismiss. I want it then to call another ViewController. I can do this from the Custom Dialog itself or from the parent If I can discover that it has returned.

What is the proper way to get to another ViewContorller?

Comment: Hi User, is your custom dialog an usual UIAlertController with a UIAlertAction?

Comment: Could you please post code whatever have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

As an option it can be achieved with delegate pattern. Here some meta code:

```
class CallerController: UIViewController {
    let dialog: CustomDialog()

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dialog.delegate = self
    }

    func showDialog() {
        dialog.show()
    }
}

extension CallerController: CustomDialogDelegate {
    func dialogWillDisappear() {
        dialog.hide()

        // navigate to another view controller here
    }
}

protocol CustomDialogDelegate {
    func dialogWillDisappear()
}

class CustomDialog {
    weak var delegate: CustomDialogDelegate?


    func someButtonDidTap() {
        delegate.dialogWillDisappear()
    }
}
```

The idea is: you manipulate with dialog in your `caller` and also performs any kind of navigation there.

Answer (score 0):

I post this with great trepidation. It is surely an unfashionable answer. I have a weak understanding of delegates and protocols. In its defence it is a direct solution to the problem.

The following function is in the calling ViewController.
var dialogSemaphore is declared as a global outside the class with an initial value of 3.
dialogSemaphore is updated to 4 when the user presses "Save" in the popup dialog, and segues to the ViewHistory viewController. nextIteration() is called just before the dialog is launched. The extra delay allows any finishing up routines before the actual segue happens.

```
    func nextIteration() {
    print ("dialogSemaphore = \(dialogSemaphore)")
    switch (dialogSemaphore){
    case 3:
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1)) {
            self.nextIteration()
        }// wait 1 sec
        break
    case 4:
        dialogSemaphore = 5
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1)) {
            self.nextIteration()
        }// wait 1 sec
        break
    case 5:
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueToViewHistory", sender: nil)
        dialogSemaphore = 3 // back to neutral
        break
    default:
        print ("wtf \(dialogSemaphore)")
        break
    }
}
```